# webサーバの冗長化に最適な構成

Tags: aws

現在、コーポレートサイトのリニューアルを行っております。
先方からサーバーの移行と、一段落ちても接続出来るような
Webサーバ冗長構成化のご要望がありました。

そこでAWSを利用した下記の構成を考えています。
＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿
月額：194.99USD（2.1万円程度）
構成：ALB、EC2×2（EBS×2：SSD100GB）、RDS for MySQL(Multi-AZ)
＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿＿

ですが、上記がベストな方法なのか判断がつかず、
別の方法があればそちらと比べたいと思っています。

ヘテムルやXサーバーに問い合わせたところ、
冗長構成としての運用はできないとのことでした。

レンタルサーバーを使用した冗長構成は不可能なのでしょうか。
VPSだと可能なのでしょうか。
ベストな方法があればご教示いただきたいです。

■現在のサーバー
さくら4G　3,888円/月
初期費用　4,320円
CPU　仮想 4Core
SSD/HDD　100GB/400GB

■移行後
・同等もしくは必要最低限のスペック
・一段落ちても接続出来るようなWebサーバ冗長構成
・メイン機でCMS生成後、ファイルが自動でサブ機にも反映される仕組み
・Wordpress（KUSANAGI）から静的CMSへの移行を相談頂いており、MT7を検討しております。

Comment: 「一段落ちても」とは具体的にどのような状態でしょうか？あと冗長構成は上を見ると際限がないため予算も結構大事なところです。

Comment: おそらく「一段落ちても」はononさんはお仕事上で使われているのかと思われますが。私はあまり聞いたことがない用語でちょっと理解が難しかったです。さくらであればVPS障害（計画メンテやネットワーク障害を除く）が起きた時や、AWSであればリージョン単位やサービス単位の障害で接続ができないときなど明確な線引はありますか？

Comment: `最適` は曖昧で、スタックオーバーフロー向けではない質問であると思います。個人的には`ALB、EC2×2（EBS×2：SSD100GB）、RDS for MySQL(Multi-AZ)` で良いように思いますが……

Comment: 「一段落ちても」とは具体的にどのような状態というのはアクティブアクティブの状態です。また、予算については現在3,888円/月ですのであまり差がでないようにはしたいのですが、冗長化ということで約2万/月は必須であるかと思っております。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！最適というのは確かに曖昧ですね。。明確な線引きについてうまく回答できず申し訳ございませんが、１台のサーバーが何らかの障害で落ちた時にサブサーバーを使用できるようにしたく、AWS以外の方法が知りたいです。

Comment: ロードバランサーで冗長構成が取れるVPS系であればConohaやWebARENA、PaaS系であれば、AWS、GCP、Azureがありますが、おそらくこれだけの情報だとどれが最適かを選択するのは難しそうですね。

Comment: 「静的CMSへの移行を相談頂いており」とのことですが、完全に静的なサイトになるのであれば、S3+CDNのような構成にすれば下手な冗長化を行うより確実かつ低コストで運用が可能です。例えばWPであれば[shifter](https://www.getshifter.io/japanese/)のようなソリューションもありますし、MTは詳しくはないのですが同様の運用事例は見つかります。当然ながらそれによるデメリットもあるので条件を満たしていてもそれを採用できるかはクライアントとの要相談とはなるでしょうが。

Comment: 最低限を求めるのであれば、可用性の最低限要件を詳しく詰めて欲しい所です。要件によってはロードバランサーすら不要で2台でDNSラウンドロビンで十分というのもあり得ます(1台サーバーが落ちているときに1/2の確率で待たされる時があるという欠点はありますが、たぶん、一番安いと思う)し、この前のAWS大規模障害のような場合も想定するのであれば、複数リージョンも考えなくてはなりません。また、コンテンツ更新の反映はどうするのかなどもあります。MTにはオフィシャルなコンテンツ同期ツールはなかったと思うので、仕組みを自分で作れないのであれば、NORENとか他の静的CMSも選択肢に入れなくてはなりません。(NORENだけで予算オーバーしそうですけど)

Comment: MTは再構築が重いのでWebサーバーとMTサーバーを分離することも検討されると良いと思います。Webサーバは静的コンテンツのみならスペックが低くても結構さばけますので、Webｘ２、MTサーバーｘ１という構成もありかもです。